# how to query join table

Tags: php, mysql, join

i have 2 table like this

```
accounts
-------------
id|
username|
password|
email|
date

bans
-------------
id|
accounts|
ip|
admin|
reason|
date|
```

for example on bans show result like this

```
5|NULL|0|1|hayo ketauan|2017-01-17 20:05:5
```

i want `bans.accounts` and `bans.admin` show `accounts.username`
i have query like this

```
SELECT `accounts`.`username`, `bans`.`ip`, `bans`.`admin`, `bans`.`reason`, `bans`.`date` 
FROM `accounts` 
INNER JOIN `bans`
  ON `accounts`.`id` = `bans`.`account`
```

and got result

```
Naufal|NULL|1.1.1.1|1|hayo ketauan|2017-01-17 20:05:5
```

i want to like this

```
Naufal|1.1.1.1|frans|hayo ketauan|2017-01-17 20:05:5
```

I'm confuse about the query.

Comment: Gonna need some examples of table data. Your one example row of bans doesn’t appear to match your fields

Comment: With the information given, do you think we can help you to magically turn your result from the first row to the second row?

Answer (score 0):

To get the username of the admin, you need to `JOIN` to the `accounts` table a second time using the `admin` value of the `bans` table. This should work:

```
SELECT `a1`.`username`, `bans`.`ip`, `a2`.`username` AS admin, `bans`.`reason`, `bans`.`date` 
FROM `accounts` `a1`
INNER JOIN `bans` ON `a1`.`id` = `bans`.`account`
INNER JOIN `accounts` `a2` ON `a2`.`id` = `bans`.`admin`
```

Comment: Ugh, my eyes hurt.

Comment: Its Work thanks a lot Nick. iam still learning mysql. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Strawberry too many backticks (just copying OP's style)? Or is there something you feel needs improving?